# Problema com JSF2 + CDI + Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jsf-2.2, cdi, injeção-de-dependência

Fala pessoal,
Estou trabalhando com JSF e empaquei aqui.
Tenho um projeto simples por enquanto, com uma página com um formulário que possui um atributo enum nele, ou seja, quando a página é carregada tem um selectItems lá que deve vir carregado do enum. 
Usando @ManagedBean e o escopo do JSF isso funciona normalmente. Mas quando eu tento migrar pra CDI o enum deixa de ser carregado.
Já testei tentando escrever um atributo simples na tela e também não vai.
Pelo que vi, deveria ser simples, mas já segui vários tutoriais e falho miseravelmente. Claro que deve ser uma bobeira minha, mas não to conseguindo ver o que é. Na console não aparece nenhuma msg de erro e a página carrega normalmente, só não traz nada do Managed Bean.
Já anotei named no bean, no enum e nada. E aí, qual que é a pegadinha?

**POM.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servelet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javaee-web-api.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
//Outras dependências (JPA, Hibernate, Wildfly)
```

WEB-INF/**beans.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="2.0" bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

WEB-INF/**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="BeanManager" 
             auth="Container"
            type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager" 
    factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/</Context>
```

**MB**

```
@Named //javax.inject.Named
@RequestScoped //javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
public class CadastroQuestaoMB implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    Questao questao;
    ...
```

Comment: Infelizmente não conheço muito de CDI, porem nesse projeto (https://github.com/algaworks/curso-javaee-primefaces) sei que eles usam, tenta dar uma olha e vê se esclarece sua dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está utilizando apenas a api do cdi. Você precisa da implementação também, já que o tomcat não implementa o cdi.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Realmente, estava faltando a implementação. Na verdade eu tentei vários tuto e coloquei essa dependência em alguns momentos do teste aqui, só que aí o servidor parava de subir e eu retirava. Descobri que não sobe por incompatibilidade do Spring Data com o CDI. Mas aí já é outra história.
Obrigado.

Comment: Beleza! Se puder marcar como resolvido para fechar o post.